# MySQL service status shows stopped after started

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed MySQL in WSL2 running Ubuntu 20.04 following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04)

I start the service using `sudo service mysql start` and received this message.

```
* Starting MySQL database server mysqld                        [ OK ]
```

However when I check the service status using `service mysql status`, I get `* MySQL is stopped.`. Checking in top showing that `mysqld` processes are started.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
25194 mysql     20   0 2070960 321408  36320 S   0.3   2.6   0:00.75 mysqld
25047 mysql     20   0    2608   1700   1552 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 mysqld_safe
```

I have no problem logging into MySQL CLI. Hence my questions are

1. Is the MySQL server actually started?
2. Am I starting the MySQL server correctly? If I started correctly, why it is showing service stopped in status?

Comment: Well you are already getting a warning. Did you investigate why? Did you check your MySQL configuration for that path? What happens if you reboot the system? As your question is also tagged as WSL do you also have a MySQL installation on your windows machine?

Comment: Already solved the path warning and reboot. Still showing MySQL service stopped although I already started it. No, I don't have MySQL installed in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be running the command without `sudo`. The MySQL service will been shown as running only when sudo is used:

```
sudo service mysql status
```